# Can I use WSPBuilder in a sharepoint continuous integration system?

Tags: sharepoint, msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity, wspbuilder

We use a teamcity server to do CI for some things, we have started with some sharepoint web part development (again) and would like to integrate this into our CI system

Using WSPBuilder on the desktop works really well but I am not sure how to fire off the tasks on the CI server. Has anyone done this? Are there MSbuild targets around to do it... or how would I go about writing my own? (is that even possible!?)

Thanks

edit: if it is not clear I want WSPBuilder on the CI server to do the building of the WSP (ideally automating the desktop experience also so the CI server and developers machines are doing the same thing)

Comment: Are you asking if you can write your own WSP or your own MSbuild target to run WSPBuilder/similarly generate a WSP?

Both are possible, with work + time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - WSPBuilder was originally a command line tool and the VS plugin part of WSPBuilder is still just an interface on top of that without much functionality of its own - install WSPBuilder on your build server and you should be able to do everything you need with Exec tasks.